Why useState setter do not work in useeffect interval function
Classic example and not clear why setter with direct value will not work
setCount(count+1) application conts only 1 and stops counting however interval function is called every second if we put a log we can see it.


const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => setCount(count+1), 1000);
    // this set count works
    // const id = setInterval(() => setCount(c => c + 1), 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);

return (<div>{count}<button onClick={()=>setCount(10)}>Give10</button></div>);
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Counter/ >);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>




Use the function state updater version that avoids the stale Javascript closure, e.g. the c => c + 1 version that works. And keep in mind for the future that in basically 100% of the use cases where the next state value depends on the current state value to use the function updater version.

The problem is the value of count captured in useEffect arrow function has the same value of 0 each time the interval hits, so effectively each second you set the state to 1 which is 0+1. The reason is the effect is run once, on first render only. This is due to how you programmed your effect to be invoked - the second useEffect's parameter is [] which literally means "run the function from first parameter once on first render".
You can read available alternatives in answers to this question: Updating state in useEffect after every second for 10 seconds

example provided is not same because here is setInterval which means effect needs to be run once and then interval run every second. I am still not clear why count captured in interval is and old value even even though it actually already changed.

The counter state is "owned" by component. The setCounter function invoked from within the interval commands React to re-render the component making the counter state updated with new value. The component-scoped counter is now updated, however your interval function was defined only once and it 'remembered' the value 0 for good. You might want to read on js closures. To make the change visible in the interval you would need to redefine your interval each second to update the counter in closure but it'd be very inefficient.

You'd better end up creating a custom function which exposes the current counter to the external world (which is your interval). Or just use the overload setCounter(c => c + 1) which accepts a callback as an argument which saves you writing your own function.

One thing you should have in mind is that the value of count inside the closure does not automatically update on each render, but from the first execution the closure will always see the value of count.
Therefore setCount(1) will always be repeatedly called because count + 1 will result to 1, which means counter will no longer increment

why count always=0 in interval function ? seems it is think like it is local variable but not state. I put button which set it to 10 but interval reset it to 0 again

The interval doesn't reset anything. What you said is correct - the counter in your interval function is just a local variable - a copy of original intial value and it never updates.

Solution to your problem
const id = setInterval(() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount+1), 1000);

In your effect you are calling setInterval with a callback which receives the initial count value 0 and setCount function. When you increment the state, setInterval does not receive the updated count state (as you passed the argument to the setInterval once).
On the other hand setState expect either a new value or a callback function which receives the previous value.

thanks pal, but this solution was in a initial problem description.

neh... It was added later, check the timestamp. :v

It was in the first revision of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/79196904/1
